# Calculate $n$ points having equal cartesian distance over a single sine wave

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'd like some help figuring out how to calculate $n$ points of the form $(x,\sin(x))$ for $x\in[0,2\pi)$, such that the Cartesian distance between them (the distance between each pair of points if you draw a straight line between them) is the same.

**My background:** I know math up to and through Algebra, have a fairly good grasp of Trig, know the Pythagorean Theorem, but only know the basic principles of Calculus (area under a curve, acceleration of acceleration, etc).

I'd like enough information so that I can either write a computer algorithm to compute the points directly (if possible) or, failing that, write an iterative search function that converges on the proper points.  It would also be nice if you could explain how it works, although I could probably figure that out myself if I had the right equation.

Comment: -1 for "No hint answers". If you're not willing to follow a good hint, you don't deserve an answer in the first place. Also the question is poorly worded: by "single sine wave", you probably mean to say that you're looking for points of the form $(x,\sin(x))$ for $x\in [0,2\pi)$. Otherwise, the question is rather trivial.

Comment: `Otherwise, the question is rather trivial` -- A fact that I'm confident you will prove in a well-written answer describing your trivial solution.  If you think you can get me from point A to point B with a mere hint, give it a shot.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Don't get shirty! I too was taken aback by the combination of your stringent requirements ("No hint answers") and your sloppy presentation. I am happy to see that you have edited your post to make it clear what you mean.

Comment: Let's assume we have points $r_1, \ldots, r_i, \ldots, r_n$. Does your criterion “*the distance between each pair of points is the same*”  mean A “between *any* pair” ($|r_i-r_j|=d$) or B “between two consecutive points” ($|r_i - r_{i+1}|=d$), where $d$ is the constant distance. If A, then all points must satisfy the additional requirement to be vertices of an object such as a equilateral triangle (n=3) or tetrahedron (n=4) – but that means (n-1)-dimensional shapes! If B, then we can choose $d$ to be arbitrarily small, and there is an infinite number of solutions. Which one do you pick?

Comment: @amon:  Let's say that there are 100 such points over the single sine wave from zero to two pi.  If you draw a straight line between any of these points and an adjacent point (the one before it on the sine curve, or the one after it), the resulting line segment will always be the same length (whatever that is).

Comment: Are you looking for exact values of $x$, or just approximate values?

Comment: @JimmyK4542: That depends what you mean by exact.  Computers cannot provide exact representations of decimal numbers, and you probably mean in reference to pi, so... not in reference to pi, or multiplied by some factor of pi so that an approximate decimal number is the result.

Comment: Robert: To be clear, is a description of an algorithm to find only decimal approximations to the $n$ points acceptable? [Your comment above still leaves one wondering if you want $x$ coordinates to be some exact expressions multiplied by $\pi$, and such would seem difficult to obtain.]

Comment: @coffeemath: Assume each x to be an ordinary Cartesian coordinate, approximated to six decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trivial solution is to have all points be the same point, such that the distance is zero. The point $(0, 0)$ lies on the sine curve and therefore represents a solution.

For non-zero distances between the points, things are a bit more complicated. We start with:

- The number of points $n$ with $n > 0$.
- A starting point $r_1$. We can always use $r_1 = (0, \sin 0) = (0, 0)$.
- A constant distance $d$. Formally, this must be in the range $(0, \frac 1 n \int_{(x_1)_x}^{2\pi}|\sin x|\,\mathrm dx)$, but let's settle for the simpler $d=\frac 1 n$ instead.

Then, given a point $r_i =: (x_a, y_a)$, we can figure out the next point $r_{i+1} =: (x_b, y_b)$:

- We know that each point is of the form $(x, \sin x)$.
- The distance between the two points is $d = |r_{i+1} - r_i|$.

The point $r_i$ is known, and point $r_{i+1} = (x_b, \sin x_b)$ with $x_b > x_a$. To calculate $r_{i+1}$, we then have to solve the following equation for $x_b$:

$$
\begin{align}
d &= |r_{i+1} - r_i|
\\\Leftrightarrow\quad
d^2 &= (x_b - x_a)^2 + (\sin x_b - y_a)^2
\end{align}
$$

Note that this includes both $b_x$ and $\sin b_x$, which makes this uncomfortably … numeric … to solve. Doing so is left as a programming exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to have more than 3 points that are equidistant.

Having 3 points equidistant on a sine wave is impossible as it requires the points to form an equilateral triangle, and at least one of the sides would need a slope steeper than $60°$ and the steepest slope on a sine wave is $45°$.

The slope of the triangle is made clear when you take one of the sides to be horizontal. The other sides will have a slope of $60°$, when you rotate the triangle one slope will become steeper until it is vertical and the other sides will have a slope of 30°.

Comment: OP said in the comments that he means that any two *consecutive* points are to be at the same distance. That is certainly possible.